# mod_rewrite - fixed and variable query string params

Tags: mod-rewrite

I want to send

www.mydomain.com/approve/SomeFunkyVariable to

www.mydomain.com/home/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=574&Itemid=85&approve=someFunkyVariable

What is the rule for this?

Comment: Where do all the params come from?

Comment: Is this in the Apache config file, or a .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Completely ignoring the params (considering you haven't mentioned them)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^approve/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=574&Itemid=85&approve=$1 [L]
```

To include the params you'll need a url like

www.mydomain.com/com_content/view/547/85/approve/SomeFunkyVariable

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)?$ index.php?option=$1&task=$2&id=$3&Itemid=$4&$5=$6 [L]
```

Comment: OK - this is the .htaccess file and the params are part of the fixed URL that is the destination.


There are already rules in the .htaccess file that map short urls to long query string urls, so can't use Pez Cuckow's rule.


I'm wanting a rule that maps 


www.mydomain.com/approve/foobar


to a 'fixed' query string url PLUS appends it with foobar ... so if the fixed query string url is in quotes it would look something like this, appended with the variable:


"www.mydomain.com/home/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=574&Itemid=85&approve="foobar

Comment: Err, thats exactly what the first half of my answer does?

Comment: Ah, don't know how I missed that! Thank you.

Comment: To summarize ([^/\.]+) just means all accepted chars, and then you refer to it with $0 (where 0 is the number of the regex above)